# How does a Cauchy sequence having a convergent subsequence help us?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, soft-question, cauchy-sequences

A standard theorem in analysis says that if $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in a normed space $X$, then $\{x_n\} \rightarrow x$ if and only if it has a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ such that $\{x_{n_k}\} \rightarrow x$.

What are some examples that show the usefulness of this result? I am able to prove it, but I don't see how it simplifies proofs. For example, in their book on functional analysis, Reed & Simon give a hint to one of their exercises that says

> To show that a Cauchy sequence converges it is only necessary to show that a subsequence converges.

Comment: It's used in the proof of the extreme value theorem

Comment: Generally speaking, proving something for a single subsequence is easier than proving it for the whole sequence, because you have the freedom to choose the subsequence.

Comment: For example, the proof that $L^p$ is a complete metric space makes use of this; by choosing a subsequence whose terms get close very quickly (i.e. $\|f_{n_k} - f_{n_{k+1}}\|_p < 2^{-k})$, you can show the subsequence converges by estimating a telescoping sum and applying the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @kieransquared Thank you, this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you to Zoe as well.